# Sencha-touch 2: how to display items in a list

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am dynamically loading data from mysql server into a list whose itemTpl is defined as below:

```
itemTpl: "<div class=\"list-item-title\">{item_name}{item_qty}</div><div class=\"list-    item-narrative\">{item_detail}</div>
```

I have my app.css defined accordingly shown below. I want my "item_name" to the leftmost side of my list and item_qty to be on the rightmost side in the same line. I can use a number of spaces (&nbsp), but I want some relative spacing between the two items.

When I am using 2 different div elements for {item_name} and {item_qty}, they appear in 2 different lines and not in the same in the list.

```
itemTpl: "<div class=\"list-item-title\">{item_name}</div><div class=\"list-item-qty\">{item_qty}</div><div class=\"list-item-narrative\">{item_detail}</div>
```

app.css

```
/* Increase height of list item so title and narrative lines fit */
.x-list .x-list-item .x-list-item-label
{
 min-height: 3.5em!important;
}
/* Move up the disclosure button to account for the list item height increase */
.x-list .x-list-disclosure {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0.85em;
right: 0.44em;
}
.list-item-title
{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    font-size:90%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right:25px;
    line-height:150%;
margin-right:520px;
}
.list-item-narrative
{
    float:left;
    width:95%;

    font-size:90%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right:25px;
}
.x-item-selected .list-item-title
{
    color:#ffffff;
}
.x-item-selected .list-item-narrative
{
    color:#ffffff;
}
.notes-list-empty-text
{
    padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your itemTpl looks like:

```
itemTpl: "<div class=\"list-item-title\">{item_name}</div><div class=\"list-item-qty\">{item_qty}</div><div class=\"list-item-narrative\">{item_detail}</div>
```

But your app.css is wrong. One class is missing: `list-item-qty`

try this one:

```
/* Increase height of list item so title and narrative lines fit */
.x-list .x-list-item .x-list-item-label
{
 min-height: 3.5em!important;
}
/* Move up the disclosure button to account for the list item height increase */
.x-list .x-list-disclosure {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0.85em;
right: 0.44em;
}
.list-item-title
{
    float:left;
    /*width:100%; //this can't be 100% width*/
    width: 75%; //could be more if you need
    font-size:90%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right:25px;
    line-height:150%;
    /*margin-right:520px;*/
}
.list-item-qty
{
    float:right;
    font-size:90%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right:25px; //You will need that when onItemDisclosure is set to true
    line-height:150%;
    clear: right;
}
.list-item-narrative
{
    float:left;
    width:95%;

    font-size:90%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right:25px;
}
.x-item-selected .list-item-title
{
    color:#ffffff;
}
.x-item-selected .list-item-narrative
{
    color:#ffffff;
}
.notes-list-empty-text
{
    padding:10px;
}
```